# How to know if someone is uzing Vuze or other torrent programes?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bittorrent, vuze

So here's the deal, I gave a couple of my friends the password to my WIFI, but since then the internet has been going too slow for long periods of time.

I suspect that one of them is using a torrent application to download movies or something, I want to know who that person is by knowing which pc is downloading through torrent.

I have the admin privileges on my network adapter, and would also like to know if there is away to see who is torrenting though my network using only my laptop by any means.
so please help me.

Comment: Most torrent clients have to do port forwarding which is automatically configured in the router when the program is set up, enter the routers firmware from your pc and look at the port forwarding tables, it will list all IP's and programs that have forwarded ports, this will at lest show if there are any torrent software's configured and the IP address of the pc that did it.

Answer (score 1):

If you own the network, router, and hardware associated with it. You can install a more advanced OS on the router (something like DD-WRT or Tomato), and use a system like nflow to monitor all traffic.

Another option is to change your password to your Wi-Fi and not actually tell them the password. If they want to use it, you put it in for them. Using this moment of time you can check the desktop/application folder for Vuze, BitTorrent, and such programs.

EDIT: A good article to read: http://www.brighthub.com/computing/smb-security/articles/48875.aspx

Comment: What if found the Vuze application, how can I stop it from accessing my network from my router, I'm not sure I know that much about routers to change their OSs.
if there is an application I can install on my pc that tells me the exact time they turn on their Vuze application and start downloading using my network it would be amazing.
Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: @Stephin As far as my knowledge goes, I have no clue if there is such an app, however, you can ask the person to remove the program before you enter the password. You can do that, or if they want to use it, cut a deal and make them pay a small portion of the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Some routers can tell you exactly which computer is consuming bandwidth. Most can give you an overall live download reading and you could correlate this with seeing who is around at the time.

If you are really serious about this you could sniff the wireless traffic and use wireshark software to examine the packets.

Comment: How do i know i have that kind of a router, and if i do have it, where can i find the bandwidth consumption.

Comment: Would wireshark can also see the traffic of the WAA users ?

Comment: Look at the model written on the router and look it up online.

Comment: See Wireshark wiki [link](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN).